# ADF Creating a LookUp Activity Query with a Variable

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We have a bug in Final Testing. I am trying to make the following Query in a LookUp Activity:

SELECT ShortName, EEOXrefCode FROM [MercerStagingDev].[MILKY-WAYTEST\AppSQLVST4DotNetDev-R].[Copy of Battelle Work Assignment Fields Jobs]
WHERE XRefCode = @variables('JobXRefCode')

I have the Set Variable showing the correct String 'JobXrefCode' but am getting a crazy error. Please help; I must figure out how to do this "syntax" this weekend.
Thanks!!
Mike Kiser

Error code
2100
Troubleshooting guide
Failure type
User configuration issue
Details
Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@variables".',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Must declare the scalar variable "@variables".,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=137,Class=15,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=2,Errors=[{Class=15,Number=137,State=2,Message=Must declare the scalar variable "@variables".,},],'

Answer (score 2):

Please try this expression:

```
SELECT ShortName, EEOXrefCode 
FROM [MercerStagingDev].[MILKY-WAYTEST\AppSQLVST4DotNetDev-R].[Copy of Battelle Work Assignment Fields Jobs] 
WHERE XRefCode = '@{variables('JobXRefCode')}'
```

---

**Update:**

> Expressions can also appear inside strings, using a feature called
> string interpolation where expressions are wrapped in @{ ... }. For
> example: "name" : "First Name: @{pipeline().parameters.firstName} Last
> Name: @{pipeline().parameters.lastName}"
>
> Using string interpolation, the result is always a string.

So when you do something like this SQL: `SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName = 'value'`, you can use this expression.

Here are some samples in ADF Tutorials:
[image]

[image]

Ref:

[Expressions and functions in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#expressions)

[Incrementally load data from Azure SQL Database to Azure Blob storage using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-portal#create-a-pipeline)

[Incrementally load data from multiple tables in SQL Server to a database in Azure SQL Database using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-multiple-tables-portal#create-the-pipeline)

Comment: Thanks! That did it! When do you know when to use Braces in that case? Thanks again! Mike Kiser

Comment: @MikeKiser Updated answer. You can have a look.

Comment: Thanks @Steve Zhao !! That helped greatly! I totally understand now....MIke Kiser

Comment: @MikeKiser You are welcome. If you think my answer helps you, you could mark it. Thanks a lot.