# Azure Synapse Pipeline Lookup / Copy activity, how to use variable for Query in place of table name

Tags: sql, copy, azure-data-factory, lookup, azure-synapse

In Azure Synapse Pipeline Lookup or Copy activity's Query setting, I am testing to use a variable for my table name so this activity can be used inside of another ForEach loop. But I keep getting this error:

> ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][BigQuery] (70) Invalid query: Query parameters cannot be used in place of table names at [4:1]

Here are a few key points of the setup:

- Pipeline variable 'v_tbl_name' to hold the table name. For this test, I hard-coded the Default value for this variable to a real table name.
- Source dataset is Google BigQuery with Prarmeter 'p_table_name' for the table name
- This setup would work with the "Table" method, but I am using the Query method because source have columns of STRUCT, the table method would give messy result. For example the column `sku STRUCT<id STRING OPTIONS(description=""), description STRING OPTIONS(description="")> OPTIONS(description=""),` without query, the data would look like `{"v":{"f":[{"v":"123-test-321"},{"v":"Log Volume"}]}}`
- Query statement is `SELECT * FROM @variables('v_tbl_name')`, with a few column names in place of the *, such as `sku.id AS sku_id, sku.description AS sku_description,` etc.
- I also tried with an additional variable v_ds_name and using the Concat function to form a table name with its dataset, but got the same error: `SELECT * FROM @concat(variables('v_ds_name'),'.',variables('v_tbl_name'))' tbl`
- Please view screenshot for additional info:[image: img1: cannot use variable at Query]

Another screenshot with dataset.tablename but got the same error
[image: img2: used dataset.tablename but got the same error]

A screenshot of this working with the "Table" method
[image]

I have looked up a similar question from this post, but I still cannot figure it out: [ADF Creating a LookUp Activity Query with a Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66502188/adf-creating-a-lookup-activity-query-with-a-variable)

Looking forward to hearing from you, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use string interpolation in the query option. If you want to write the ADF dynamic content in query string, you need to write the dynamic content expression (variables or functions) inside `@{}`.

**This is a sample demo:**

Write your query like this.

```
select * from @{variables('table_name')}
```

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

The `concat()` also needs to be inside the `@{}` like below.

```
select * from @{concat(variables('v_ds_name'),'.',variables('v_tbl_name'))}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this demo! This finally clicked for me! Now I also understand the other post about the string interpolation.